# Multi-variate multistep time series Forecasting for non-stationary data

Tags: time-series, forecasting, stationarity, unevenly-spaced-time-series, sensor-data

[image]The problem is that I have a very special time series. It is sensors data for a machine. I have about 400 sensor data which I want to use to forecast the machine advancing speed.
The data contain a lot of zeros (for the downtime phases and for the rest phases).

The data doesn't have hourly or monthly seasonality, but for each operating phase has a different speed range and the operating phases are different each time. Is there any way to forecast the speed for the next operating phase?

This post is hidden. It was deleted 6 days ago by Sycorax♦.
sensor reading of the advancing speed (on 10 sec bases)

this is a plot of the target. i want to use sensors data of a machine to forecast its speed. i have 86 features. they are registered on 10 sec bases. the goal is to do feature selection to reduce dimensionality then time series forecasting to predict the speed multi steps in the furure. the specialty of these data is that they are not time related. they change due to the operating situation but the time factor is still important because the speed in the next time step is mostly related to the speed in the last few steps.

Comment: Can you show us a plot of the series?  My first stop searching for forecasting ideas is https://robjhyndman.com/hyndsight/

Comment: Sorry, that was the wrong link! I will update NOW

Comment: Thanks @kjetilbhalvorsen.

Comment: Please register &/or merge your accounts (you can find 
information on how to do this in the **My Account** 
section of our [help]), then you will be able to 
edit & comment on your own question.